# Check if keyword arguments exist in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a function collect extra keyword arguments using `...`, so it is like `function f(args=0; kwargs...)`. I want to check if a keyword argument, let' say, `a`, exists in `kwargs`.

What I do probably is not an elegant way, I first create a `Dict` to store the keywords and corresponding values `kwargs_dict=[key=>value for (key, value) in kwargs]`, then I use `haskey(kwargs_dict, :a)` to check if `a` is a key in the dict. Then I get its value by `kwargs_dict[:a]`.

```
function f(; kwargs...)
   kwargs_dict = [key=>value for (key, value) in kwargs]
   haskey(kwargs_dict, :a)
   a_value = kwargs_dict[:a]
end

f(args=0, a=2)
> true

f(args=0)
> false
```

I wonder if there is better way to check if the keyword argument `a` is in `kwargs` and to get the value of the existed keyword argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method is to use default values for named keyword variables. With the default being a special value (a.k.a sentinel value). When a value is supplied by the user it overrides the default and this can easily be checked. `nothing` is a commonly used value. Specifically, for the example in the question:

```
julia> function g(; a = nothing, kwargs...)
    kwargs_dict = [key=>value for (key, value) in kwargs]
    a != nothing
end
g (generic function with 1 method)
```

Gives the functionality:

```
julia> g(args=0, a=2)
true
julia> g(args=0)
false
```

The advantage is 1st speed - default valued keyword arguments can avoid the `kwargs` dictionary and if possible optimization will drop the whole dictionary setup code. The 2nd advantage could be readability (but to each his own taste).

Comment: This is a good approach in many cases, but make sure to watch out for type instabilities:

`
#= good =#
f(;a::Int=0) = a;
g(use::Bool) = use ? f(a=1) : f();
@code_warntype g(true);

#= bad =#
f(;a=nothing) = a==nothing ? 0 : a;
g(use::Bool) = use ? f(a=1) : f();
@code_warntype g(true)
`

Answer (score 7):

You can just pass `kwargs` to the `Dict` constructor to get a dictionary representation of the kwargs. For example:

```
kwargs_dict = Dict(kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks that is an elegant way to make the dict.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:
You could also define

```
function f(; kwargs...)
    keys = [k for (k, v) ∈ kwargs]
    :a ∈ keys
end
```

If you just want to provide a value in case no kwarg is supplied, you can also do

```
function f(; kwargs...)
    a = get(kwargs, :a, "my default value for a")
end
```

which allows you to

```
julia> f(ab = "a")
"my default value for a"

julia> f(a = "a")
"a"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward and allocation-free method (since at least Julia 1.6) is to check

```
:a in keys(kwargs)
```

If true, you can retrieve the value with

```
a = values(kwargs).a
```

Here is a slightly modified version of your example:

```
function f(; kwargs...)
    if :a in keys(kwargs)
        a = values(kwargs).a
        if a > 0
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

julia> @btime f(a=2)
  0.900 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
true

julia> @btime f(b=2)
  0.900 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
false
```